# UWP - WinRT xaml toolkit TreeView in Flyout, changes selection after flyout closes

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, treeview, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I am currently trying to use WinRT xaml ToolKit TreeView component since it is not supported in UWP natively.

TreeView is inside a button Flyout. When I press the button I want Flyout to appear so I can select an item from the tree. And I bind a command from ViewModel to SelectedItemChanged event:

```
<Button
   x:Name="btnFilter"
   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
   Command="{Binding OpenFiltersCommand}"
   Style="{StaticResource SecondaryMenuButtonStyle}">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <Image
       Width="28"
       Margin="0,0,4,0"
       Source="{StaticResource FilterIcon}" />
     <TextBlock x:Uid="Filter" Style="{StaticResource GrayTextBlockStyle}" />
   </StackPanel>
   <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
     <controls1:CustomFlyout IsOpen="{Binding IsFiltersOpen, Mode=TwoWay}" Parent="{Binding ElementName=btnFilter}">
        <controls2:TreeView
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DefaultTreeViewItem}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TreeViewItemTemplate}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding BuildingTree}"
          Style="{StaticResource DefaultTreeViewStyle}">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
              <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ChangeRoomCommand}" />
              </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
         </controls2:TreeView>
      </controls1:CustomFlyout>
   </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</Button>
```

After I select an item from TreeView, SelectedItemChanged event fires as it should, but afterwards I close the Flyout and the event fires again. The second time it usually fires saying new selected element is next after current's parent. So for example if I have this structure:

```
1
--1.0
--1.1
--1.2
2
--2.0
--2.1
```

So if I select --1.1 first SelectedItemChanged will fire with --1.1 element, and afterwards it will fire with 2 as new selected item.

Note: I am using CustomFlyout component which I can close from ViewModel, but I also tested this with regular Flyout and same thing happens after I close Flyout by clicking outside of it.

UPDATE: I've downloaded WinRT code and started debugging the TreeView component locally. In TreeViewItem.cs I've found the source of the problem in this function:

```
    protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Since the GotFocus event will bubble up to the parent
        // TreeViewItem (which will make it think it's also selected), it
        // needs to ignore that event when it's first been handled by one of
        // its nested children.  We use the IgnoreNextGotFocus flag to
        // notify our parent that GotFocus has already been handled.
        TreeViewItem parent = ParentTreeViewItem;
        if (parent != null)
        {
            parent.CancelGotFocusBubble = true;
        }

        try
        {
            if (Interaction.AllowGotFocus(e) && !CancelGotFocusBubble)
            {
                // Select the item when it's focused
                Select(true);

                // ActivateAsync the selection
                IsSelectionActive = true;
                UpdateVisualState(true);

                Interaction.OnGotFocusBase();
                base.OnGotFocus(e);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            CancelGotFocusBubble = false;
        }            
    }
```

From what I can tell when element gets focus sometimes it fails to find it's parent and prevent propagating the event upwards in the tree.

I've also opened an [issue](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/issues/49) on their github repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said previously it seems this is a bug in WinRT TreeView component however I managed to prevent (hard fix) this behavior by binding "IsEnabled" property to IsFiltersOpen property from my ViewModel.

This way when I select my element I close the Flyout and disable TreeView component, which prevents it from updating.